# Findbugs `NP_NULL_ON_SOME_PATH_FROM_RETURN_VALUE`

Tags: java, jenkins-plugins, findbugs

While trying to release a jenkins plugin maven reported some findbugs errors that I can not figure out how to fix.

```
[INFO] Possible null pointer dereference in com.datapipe.jenkins.vault.VaultBuildWrapper$DescriptorImpl.doFillAuthTokenCredentialIdItems() due to return value of called method [com.datapipe.jenkins.vault.VaultBuildWrapper$DescriptorImpl, com.datapipe.jenkins.vault.VaultBuildWrapper$DescriptorImpl] Dereferenced at VaultBuildWrapper.java:[line 326]Known null at VaultBuildWrapper.java:[line 326] NP_NULL_ON_SOME_PATH_FROM_RETURN_VALUE
[INFO] Possible null pointer dereference in com.datapipe.jenkins.vault.VaultBuildWrapper$DescriptorImpl.doFillAuthTokenCredentialIdItems() due to return value of called method [com.datapipe.jenkins.vault.VaultBuildWrapper$DescriptorImpl, com.datapipe.jenkins.vault.VaultBuildWrapper$DescriptorImpl] Method invoked at VaultBuildWrapper.java:[line 329]Known null at VaultBuildWrapper.java:[line 329] NP_NULL_ON_SOME_PATH_FROM_RETURN_VALUE
```

The lines in question fall in the following function:

```
public ListBoxModel doFillAuthTokenCredentialIdItems(){
  if (!Jenkins.getInstance().hasPermission(Jenkins.ADMINISTER)) {
    return new ListBoxModel();
  }
  AbstractIdCredentialsListBoxModel model = new StandardListBoxModel().includeEmptyValue().includeAs(ACL.SYSTEM, Jenkins.getInstance(), VaultTokenCredential.class);
  return model;
}
```

I have tried adding the following null check to no avail:

```
public ListBoxModel doFillAuthTokenCredentialIdItems(){
  Jenkins jenkins = Jenkins.getInstance();

  if (jenkins == null) {
    return new ListBoxModel();
  }

  if (!jenkins.hasPermission(Jenkins.ADMINISTER)) {
    return new ListBoxModel();
  }
  AbstractIdCredentialsListBoxModel model = new StandardListBoxModel().includeEmptyValue().includeAs(ACL.SYSTEM, jenkins, VaultTokenCredential.class);
  return model;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why but creating the new `ListBoxModel` before returning it did the trick.

```
public ListBoxModel doFillAuthTokenCredentialIdItems() {
  final ListBoxModel lbm = new ListBoxModel();
  final Jenkins jenkins = Jenkins.getInstance();

  if (jenkins == null) {
    return lbm;
  }

  if (!jenkins.hasPermission(Jenkins.ADMINISTER)) {
    return lbm;
  }
  AbstractIdCredentialsListBoxModel model = new StandardListBoxModel().includeEmptyValue().includeAs(ACL.SYSTEM, jenkins, VaultTokenCredential.class);
  return model;
}
```